# convert this File into APK

Tags: code.org

I had created this code.org file and they had provided the link
https://studio.code.org/projects/applab/-hUNZI_6cd9viQh-Br1MBrn4t8aHw7Gefou3r_9o1gg/edit

Now I want to view it on mobile as a real app but the link only opens it in a browser.
So How should I convert it into an APK file to get the real app on my phone?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. APK's are android packages built from Java. From what I assume, code.org projects are privately stored and compiled in a way that cannot be exported

Answer (score -1):

This is a really good website that allows you to view how to make a file into a APK format. Here is the link, https://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/mobile-apps/how-to-create-a-publishable-apk-file-for-your-android-app/, it will be very helpful if you have an android device.